# Get Data from API response and show in table

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to create a table which displays updates in intervals by using ajax calls to get the data from the server.

I am trying to get the data from my server and update my table view with the new data.

this is my Javascript function.

```
function updateSlaveTable() {

  fetch('{{route(' pusher ')}}', {
        method: 'post',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json', // sent request
          'Accept': 'application/json' // expected data sent back
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "mac": "{{$slaves['mac']}}"
        })
      })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(function(res) {
      //alert(JSON.stringify(res));
      //setInterval(updateSlaveTable, 1000)

      $.getJSON("res.json", function(slaves) {
        var slave_data = '';
        $.each(res.slave_id, function(key, value) {
          // if(value.type == "door_sensor")
          //{
          slave_data += '<tr>';
          slave_data += '<td>' + value.name + '</td>';
          slave_data += '<td>' + value.slave_id + '</td>';
          slave_data += '<td>' + value.type + '</td>';
          slave_data += '<td>' + value.status + '</td>';
          slave_data += '<td>' + value.value + '</td>';
          slave_data += '<td>' + value.mode + '</td>';
          slave_data += '<td>' + value.name1 + '</td>';
          slave_data += '<td>' + value.name2 + '</td>';
          slave_data += '<td>' + value.name3 + '</td>';
          slave_data += '<td>' + value.name4 + '</td>';
          slave_data += '<td>' + value.s1 + '</td>';
          slave_data += '<td>' + value.s2 + '</td>';
          slave_data += '<td>' + value.s3 + '</td>';
          slave_data += '<td>' + value.s4 + '</td>';
          slave_data += '<td>' + value.voltage + '</td>';
          slave_data += '<td>' + value.temp + '</td>';
          slave_data += '<td>' + value.hum + '</td>';
          slave_data += '</tr>';
          // }     
        });
        $('#slave_table').append(slave_data);
      });
    });

})
.catch(function(error) {
  // alert(error);
  // setInterval(updateSlaveTable, 1000); // <-- there was a network problem, 
  //     but still, program the next one!
})

}

updateSlaveTable();
```

I get the data correctly to the function. The Response is below

```
{
"3":
    {"value":"in value same","status":"in status same","volt":"in volt same"},
"4":
    {"value":"in value same","status":"in status same","volt":"in volt same"},
"5":
    {"status":"in status same","temp":"in temp same","hum":"in humidity same","volt":"in volt same"},
"6":
    {"status":"in status same","volt":"in volt same"},
"7":
    {"status":"in status same","s1":"in s1 same","s2":"in s2 same","s3":"in s3 same"},
"9":
    {"status":"in status same","temp":"in temp same","hum":"in humidity same","volt":"in volt same"},
"10":
    {"value":"in value same","status":"in status same","volt":"in volt same"},

"message":"no Change"
}
```

I have little experience in JavaScript so please do not mind the simple question

Comment: "I get the data correctly to the function". Your code contains two ajax calls: one called by fetch(). And one called by $.getJSON(). Which one of these is your sample data the result of? And precisely what issue are you facing? What is going wrong in your code when you run it?

Comment: the output shared is from the fetch(). Now nothings wrong actually all i want to do is to rather than using alert to display the data i want to append it in my table. That is why i was trying to use getJson to get data and show in the table. 

Hence all i want is to display the output in table

Comment: If nothing's wrong then why are you asking? You've got some code which tries to create table data...presumably it doesn't do what you wanted it to? So, please describe what goes wrong. I'm going to guess the loop doesn't work because I can't see any `slave_id` in your result. Your code needs to match the structure properly.

Comment: And what is the purpose of the $.getJSON call, by the way? You don't appear to do anything with that bit of the data.

Comment: Well nothing is wrong with the fetch() but the result i am getting and storing in res i want that to be showed in the table. 

I was trying to to use getJson to get the data and show them in the table. I used this before but that was with a saved .json file but now im not saving it in file. Directly call the api.

Comment: Ok so it sounds like you can just remove the $.getJSON bit.

Comment: Yes i did that now. How do i now display then? :P

Comment: After that try `$.each(res,` instead of `$.each(res.slave_id,` - your result doesn't seem to have a slave_id property. And then after that, inside the loop, your result objects only have "value", "status and "volt" properties. I don't know where you think all the names like slave_id, type, mode, name1, name2 etc is coming from. Look at your own sample data, clearly it isn't there. Remove the lines that try to use those non-existent properties

Comment: BTW have you been checking your browser's Console (in the Developer tools) when running this? I'd have expected you'd be getting some errors which might have given you clues how to solve this yourself.

Comment: Well the devices who's values are changed are to be updated in the table. It checks for changes from the API e.g. battery volts were 50 after an hour then went to 49 so we update the table with the new values. Whenever there is a change in value it triggers. So In the table im trying to get all the values. But now i am confused what about the values of things that haven't changed?

Comment: Right so you want to update existing rows in the table, not create new ones? That wasn't really clear before. If you want to replace specific cells you'll need a way to identify the correct row in the markup, and then the correct cell for each value. Can you show the existing HTML? Do the `<tr>`s contain any kind of identifier (e.g. an "id" attribute)?

Comment: Yes. Once api is run it stores all the data in the table. Then if there is a change it updates the value in it. So i need to code that

Comment: Also your results don't seem to have IDs either, so it's unclear how you're going to know which one corresponds to each table row

Comment: My Ids are set through when the page loads for the first time. The <tr> ids are mapped to reflect the slave device id so when i call for updates the object contains the slave id. Then i can clearly check which row i have to change. The problem is that i do not know how to actually change the cell data, or how to perform basic JavaScript functions so i need some guidance on that.

Comment: The data you've shown here doesn't contain a slave ID as far as I can see. So you'll never be able to map it to the right row. Unless you haven't shown us a full sample of the data, I suggest you'll need to amend the server-side code to return a more useful result. As for how to update the cells, you can check JavaScript and jQuery documentation for how you alter the text of an element. If the element has an ID, you can fetch it easily. If the element (e.g. a cell) is _within_ an element which has an id, you can use jQuery's `.find()` to locate the child within the parent.

Answer (score 1):

If your data in `res` what I saw below, then the `$.each(res.slave_id,...` is not valid, because the `res` hasn't slave_id property. Your keys are numbers, so you can iterate them with `Object.keys(res).map(key => res[key]).forEach(obj => console.log(obj))`.

After the map, you'll get an object array, this values can be the table rows.

Comment: Ok i got the objects in the console still i need help in showing them in the table

Comment: Okay, then you need to store the `Object.keys(res).map(key => res[key])` into a variable. e.g.: name it `objectArray`
Then `$('#slave_table').append(
 objectArray.map(object => '<tr>' + '<td>' + object.value +'</td>' + '<td>' + object.status +'</td>' + '<td>' + object.volt+'</td>' + '</tr>')
);`